# How can you close an open message collector with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I want to end an open message collector

Here is the code I have

```js
const collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id)
collector.on('collect', msg => {
    // here is where I want it to close
    msg.reply("You win!")
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop a message collector from collecting messages simply use [`MessageCollector.stop()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector?scrollTo=stop)

Your code will look something like this :

```js
const collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id)
collector.on('collect', msg => {
  collector.stop()
  msg.reply("You win!")
})
```

This is something really simple to find, I just googled it and found it easily